# How to get event details in middleware for socket.io

Tags: node.js, logging, socket.io

I am trying to log the `event name` and `parameter` for each event on my Node server. For this purpose I used

```
io.use(function(socket, next){
  // how to get event name out of socket.
});
```

Now, I got stuck while trying to get event name and arguments. To me, it looks like common demand from API dev, so I am pretty sure there must be some way to the library to get that, I have tried to read the docs and source but I am not able to get the stuff.

Comment: Have you tried printing the properties of `socket` using [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to see if there's a property that has the data you need? This can be a bit of work but it's the best way to find the right property if it's not in the documentation.

Comment: I tried to inspect `socket.request` but haven't inspected `socket` itself.

Comment: I wanted to know this as well. I used [recursive-iterator](https://github.com/nervgh/recursive-iterator) to go through all properties in the `socket` object recursively but couldn't find the string `"connection"` for that event. In the socket.io source code there's an `ondecoded` which calls `onpacket` with the id/message. And the `use` middleware doesn't seem to be involved in any of that (in fact it seems it happens before all that) so that's probably why this detail isn't available here. Would really appreciate if someone could provide a more authoritative answer on this though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The socket events needs to be handled properly,in any case if an event is not handled there will be no response.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var sessionMiddleWare=(session({secret: 'secret key', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true,cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 300000 },rolling: true}));

app.use(sessionMiddleWare)

io.use(function(socket, next) {
  sessionMiddleWare(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {  // On Socket connection.
   // inside this you can use different events

   //event name and parameters can be found in socket variable.

   console.log(socket.id) // prints the id sent from the client.
   console.log(socket.data) // prints the data sent from the client.

   // example event

   socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {  // Event sample.
        console.log('joining room', room);
        socket.room=room;
        socket.join(room);
    });
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This as its current code cannot logs upon every event, only on `connection`.